# Firebase storage rules, `request.resource.md5hash` is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm trying to build a web app using FireBase backend and I have a storage rule as the following:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/stuff.appspot.com/o {
    match /images/{fname}
    {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.resource.md5hash != null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to put data to `images/filename`, I'm getting a `storage/unauthorized` error. If I remove the condition and set to just `true`, it works as expected and therefore I think the `request.resource.md5hash` is null.

What am I missing? Because I would expect any file to have a non-null md5 hash.

Additional notes:

- If I remove the md5 condition and upload a file without any check, I can get the `md5Hash` in the client of the uploaded file. Therefore, a hash is actually being calculated at some point.
- In [the reference about storage rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#properties_1) `md5hash` field is used, so it's expected to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. The property is actually `md5Hash` (our reference docs are wrong, I just fixed them)
2. The `md5Hash` is currently not being passed through to rules (yep, it's a bug, and we're fixing it now, though it takes some time to roll out to production)

We're working on passing the MD5 through, so hold tight :)

Comment: I've tried `md5Hash` before asking the question too which didn't work and since docs used both, I thought fields were case insensitive.
Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Nope, they're case sensitive. Sorry for the issue :(

Comment: can you use md5Hash in database rules?

Comment: @okwme no, as the JSON in the database isn't hashed